# Qt/C++, QObject::connect() effect on currently executed function?

Tags: qobject

I always use QObject::connect() in all my applications but it is not clear to me its effect when my program is currently inside a function. Suppose I have the following code:

```
void main() {
    //other stuffs here
    QObject::connect(xxx,SIGNAL(yyy()),this,SLOT(zzz());
}

void aFunction()
{
    //a bunch of codes here

    //i am here when suddenly signal is emitted from QObject::connect();

    //another bunch of codes here
}
```

I assume that when the signal is emitted, QObject::connect leaves the function "aFunction()" to execute "zzz()". What will happen to the remaining codes in the "aFunction()"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can understand the confusion, coming from procedural to event based programming gives me same experience like you do now.

Short answer: 
in non multi threaded environment, slot `zzz()` will be executed after `aFunction()` finishes. In fact, the signal probably gets emitted after aFunction finishes. 
in multi threaded env., same thing but it is *"after some time"*, not after.

Key to understanding this is Event Loop. `QApplication::exec()` runs a forever loop polling for event. New event is then handled, signals get emitted and depending on the fifth argument of `QObject::connect` which is a `Qt::ConnectionType`, ultimately runs the connected slot. You can read [QObject documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qobject.html#connect) for more detail..

So your `aFunction` probably gets called after some signal, so after it is finished, it's back to event loop again, then your 'suddenly emitted' signal actually gets emitted and `zzz` is executed.

Even in multi threading environment, inter thread signals and slots work with `Qt::QueuedConnection` which basically just posts the emitted signal to corresponding thread so that when that thread's event loop come around to process it - it will be executed sequentially as well.

Ultimately what you will have to remember is that this Turing Machine called computers is executing **sequences** of codes, whether it's semi paralel (e.g time sharing, pipelining) or truly paralel (e.g multi cores, multi cpu) the part where codes get sent (or distributed? or fetched?) to its execution will always run in sequences or in one or more ways have to be simulated to be sequential so that no code is executed twice in multiple execution node.

There is no "suddenly"

Comment: Funny I just noticed this question is posted at March. Hopefully OP is still around..